# How can I get Eclipse on OSX to use Java 1.6?

Tags: java, eclipse, java-6

I just installed Java 1.6 on my OSX and everything works brilliantly, except that Eclipse refuses to start. It puts up a huge prompt from which I can't copy/paste, but it's clearly stating that it wants to be using Java 1.5 and can't find it anymore.

I don't see anything in its configuration files about which version of Java it should be looking for. Has anyone dealt with this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

on /Applications/Eclipse/Eclipse.app right click and choose "Show Package Contents"
open Contents/Info.plist with a text editor *NOT* plist editor

add
 `<string>-vm</string>
<string>/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.5.0/Commands/java</string>`

to

```
<key>Eclipse</key>
        <array>
<!-- add it here -->
</array>
```

save it and restart.

Comment: /1.5.0/Commands/java seems to be a link to /Home/bin/java, which is now 1.6. Should I use /1.5.0/home/bin/java instead?

Comment: The link is to ../Home/bin/java which has an absolute path of /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.5.0/Home/bin/java

Comment: Don't forget that the same applies to the default VM when launching Java processes from within Eclipse. Specifically, if you are doing Eclipse plugin/RCP development, you will need to specify the 1.5 VM as default for running your applications from within Eclipse launch configurations or preferences.

Comment: I just have to thank you Clint. I've been struggling with this for 4 days. Opened threads on StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6650547/macosx-snow-leopard-and-eclipse-error-starting-eclipse-no-java-virtual-machine/6704946#6704946

Opened theme on eclipse forums: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/220101/

and nowhere on net says that -vm arguments go to Eclipse array of info.plist file.

Answer (score 3):

Unless I'm mistaken, the Java 1.6 vm on the Mac is 64 bit only.  To use it, you'll need a 64bit version of Eclipse.  The only 64bit port of eclipse on the mac is the new cocoa build, find it [here](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/I20090611-1540/index.php).

In a few weeks, the [Galileo release](http://www.eclipse.org/galileo/) will be finished, there you can find the 64 bit cocoa port by going to Eclipse Classic -> Other Downloads.

If you want to keep your current eclipse install, you'll have to do as the other answers suggest and change them to use 1.5

Comment: Galileo is released in less than a week and, although it supports 64 bit, I'd still recommend using the 32 bit version. The 64 bit does seem a bit more memory hungry.

Comment: Isn't that the whole point of 64bit? (Except on MacOS where you have no choice for java6).  The advantage of 64 bit is addressing more memory, which comes at the cost of larger objects since the pointers are twice as large.  (I don't know if the mac vm does compressed references.)

Comment: The point is to enable addressing larger space. However, if on a normal operation (having two JVMs do exactly the same thing) the 64-bit JVM consumes more memory, there's no point in running it in 64-bit mode.

Answer (score 0):

You should switch to your previous version of Java, under Utilities, Java Preferences, and dragging 1.5 32 bit as the first choice.

The reason for the error is that the bundled SWT JINI libraries seem to be compiled for only certain platforms.

You can always check the Console for specific error messages.

Comment: You mean do this just while running Eclipse? I need 1.6 to do other things.