# MacOSX Snow Leopard and Eclipse: Error starting Eclipse (No Java virtual machine....)

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

This is so frustrating.

I did no update of java nor eclipse and suddenly I can't open eclipse. I even didn't install any other programs. Here is the error:

[image: error]

I've tried everything.
I updated to new java version and no luck on that:
[image: java versions]

I downloaded the newest eclipse and had no luck.

Then I updated eclipse's Info.plist file:

Added:
 `<string>-vm</string><string>/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/Commands/java</string>`

[image: Info.plist]

From terminal:

[image: terminal]

What else could I do?

EDIT:

Path variable:

[image: PATH]

EDIT 2: Strange behavior. If I go right click on eclipse.app and navigate through: Contents/MacOS/eclipse and double click it then a terminal opens and eclipse starts: [image: eclipseFromTermina]

Why is that so. I want to run eclipse directly from eclipse.app, not through Contents/.....

EDIT 3:

I see that someone had the same exact problem as me but I haven' find the solution yet: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/107226/

Comment: Where is your JRE installed (exact directory) in your machine?

Comment: here is java on my computer: http://img10.imageshack.us/img10/4643/screenshot20110711at328.png

Comment: show us your $PATH variable please

Comment: I edited question with photo of path variable.

Comment: Please see my Edit no 2.

Comment: Ooh!! You lucky boy! You're running OSX!!

Comment: Hi Vale i have 2 questions for you, are you tryin to install Eclipse Helios? and for what kind of development, Blackberry android?

Comment: @Jorgesys This thing happened while I had Helios. Then I downloaded new version (Indigo) and the problem remained the same. Development is "regular" - Java for EE developers.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

OK, after a few days of struggling and with no luck on this thread and Eclipse forums [THREAD](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/220101/) I started a bounty for this question and had no correct answer.

I found a solution to this problem ([this stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014376/how-can-i-get-eclipse-on-osx-to-use-java-1-6)).

**ANSWER:**

You need to edit the Eclipse.app/Contents/Info.plist file and add two lines in it:

[image]

Nowhere stated that this lines had to go in Eclipse array but just somewhere up as key-string.

If you don't have Xcode, edit that file with textedit:

```
    <key>Eclipse</key>
<array>
    <string>-vm</string>
    <string>/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Home/bin/java</string>
    <string>-keyring</string>
    <string>~/.eclipse_keyring</string>
    <string>-showlocation</string>
</array>
```

Comment: This one works. Setting the vm option in eclipse.ini seems to get overwritten. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 3):

Try moving your workspace and deleting the configs (`rm -rf ~/.eclipse`). Sometimes Eclipse messes up its env and needs to be reset.

Comment: I don't have .eclipse file in -rf ~/

Comment: Where could I find .eclipse file because it is not in my ./ folder?

Comment: If your .eclipse folder is not in ~ then it might be in the Eclipse folder itself in eclipse/.eclipseproduct .

Comment: Should I then delete that file? --> .eclipseproduct? There are only 3 lines in that file and they don't look like some configuration lines:

LINE 1:name=Eclipse Platform
LINE 2:id=org.eclipse.platform
LINE 3:version=3.7.0

Answer (score 2):

Editing the plist file is not the recommended way of setting the JVM. See http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_run_Eclipse%3F#Find_the_JVM and it points you to http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#Specifying_the_JVM

Basically inside Eclipse.app/MacOS/eclipse.ini is where you'll want to specify command line arguments that get passed to eclipse by default. Granted the plist's array of arguments are also used, but that isn't how the Eclipse docs themselves recommend setting arguments (and it is possible that as a result, it might get wiped when you update Eclipse again).

You'd want to remove the vm entry from that Array in the plist and instead add the following in the eclipse.ini before "-vmargs":

```
-vm
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/Home/bin/java
```

Answer (score 1):

try to add this to your `~/.profile`

```
export JAVA_HOME=/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/Home/
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: Did that. I needed to create .profile file. Edited it with nano. Now my PATH variable looks like this: http://img577.imageshack.us/img577/8483/screenshot20110711at358.png  but still the same error while starting eclipse.

Comment: I have included JDK in PATH variable but the same error appears. I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a file `~/.MacOSX/environment.plist` and add `JAVA_HOME => /Library/Java/Home` entry into it.
If you have XCode installed, use it to add entry.
Otherwise, use plain text editor:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>JAVA_HOME</key>
    <string>/Library/Java/Home</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

After that, restart MaxOS or logout/login.

See
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPRuntimeConfig/Articles/EnvironmentVars.html for details.

Cheers,
Max

Comment: I already did that few days ago but this is not the solution. I just found a solution a few moments ago and answered my question. Cheers.

Comment: Did you cleanup eclipse's Info.plist changes you made ?

Comment: I don't understand. I put a picture of mine Info.plist in my answer.

Comment: I mean that you have to cleanup any alterations you made to Info.plist in order to test enviroment.plist solution.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same issue but a simple

```
chmod +x Contents/MacOS/eclipse
```

in the package content, did the trick.

Comment: Looks better then my solution with editing info.plist. But I won't touch anything now when it works.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed this using a 2 step solution:

*1. Set JAVA_HOME correctly:*

Find out the Java JDK location:

```
/usr/libexec/java_home
```

Create the ~/.bash_profile if needed:

```
touch ~/.bash_profile
```

Edit the .bash_profile file using TextEdit, and add the following lines (change the paths as necessary):

> export
>   JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/ export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

*2. Set the alias to be executable:*

From the eclipse install location, run:

```
chmod +x ./eclipse
```

Now to activate Eclipse I open Finder, navigate the to eclipse installation directory and double click the **alias** file (named eclipse, but without the eclipse icon).